# How do I open a project without a .sln file in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I was writing this program all in Vim and now I'm thinking of moving to Visual Studio, but since I didn't start in Visual Studio in the first place, there is no .sln file to open from. How should I open such a project in Visual Studio?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/754c3hy7.aspx

Comment: Do you have a .csproj or .vbproj file, or just some individual .cs or .vb files?

Comment: All I have is a bunch of .cpp and .h files.

Comment: thank you @GJK, it looks like I have to use the Professional version of VS

Comment: How many files are you talking about?  Just create a new project in Visual Studio and copy/paste your .cpp and .h files into it.

Comment: @mikey That actually is a great idea! Thanks lol

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a *.csproj file exists, you can build a new solution by Visual Studio at first. Next, you can open this *.csproj file in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks but what should I do if all I have is .h and .cpp files

Answer (score 48):

If you have a web project (without a .sln), you must do:

Menu *File* → *Open* → *Web Site...*

And choose the folder where the project is.

Comment: Hello @CésarJavierMendoza could you take a look to this question please? In the project on github there isn't a sln file. How can I open the project? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77140823/option-build-solution-in-visual-studio-2022-doesnt-appear

Answer (score 15):

An even simpler way in Visual Studio is to follow this:

Menu *File* → *New* → *Project from existing code*

Choose the source file location and a .csproj and .sln file is created.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't see that on Mac. I currently have Visual Studio for Mac Professional v8.3.3

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way to do this (assuming this is not a web project, as indicated in another answer) would most likely be to:

1. Create a new project (of the desired type), which should also create the solution for it to live within.
2. In the solution explorer, right click and select "Add > Existing item..."
3. Insert all individual files that belong in this new project.

It's probably also worth noting that it's a good idea to double check the project setting, namespaces, etc. before you get too far with building up your project to avoid potential issues later.